# Omit props from type that was already passed via different variable

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
function useStuff<T>(props: Partial<T>) {
    const open = (addProps: Omit<T, keyof typeof props>) => {
        console.info(addProps);
    };
    return {open};
}

function App() {
    const {open} = useStuff<{
        foo: string;
        bar: string;
    }>({foo: 'bar'});
    // expect typescript to show error that bar property is missing
    // however no error is shown
    return open({})
}
```

i have a useStuff function, which accepts generic type, and returns a open method which also accepts the same generic type. What i want to achieve is to be able to pass partial props directly to useStuff method and then rest of the props which wasn't passed directly would be required to pass via open method.

I've addded a small example of what i'm trying to achieve and what's not working

---EDIT---

For the moment i've added another generic to tell which props will be passed to through useStuff method and omit those props from open method

```
function useStuff<T, K>(props: K) {
    const open = (addProps: Omit<T, keyof K>) => {
        console.info(addProps);
    };
    return {open};
}

type Props = {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

function App() {
    const {open} = useStuff<Props, Pick<Props, 'foo'>>({foo: 'bar'});
    // when Pick<Props, 'foo'> is passed to useStuff
    // now typescript shows error that property bar is missing
    return open({})
}
```

though would love to know if it's possible to do without specifically typing which props go where

Comment: You can achieve this by using a function to create your useStuff. https://tsplay.dev/m0V9Pw